# changing href="example" to href="/example"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model, which returns html from the database, and I need to change the links that don't have the forward slash (but obviously not touch the hard coded links with http: or already slashes)

one example
href="example" to href="/example" the value in href is unknown and could be anything.
so if it's just one word without a slash add it. If it has http: or a slash already, don't change it

Comment: what specifically is your question?

Comment: And so what is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CamBruce how to take href="<any value>" and change it to href="/<any value>". The extra slash is needed, but obviously not for links that have http:// or /, or ~/ already

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) to get that done?

You could make it replace href=" >> href="/

```
String s = "href=\"example\"";
s.Replace("href=\"", "href=\"/");
```

That would return

```
href="/example"
```

Comment: but example could be anything, the value is not known. it could be example, http://example.com (which I don't want to change)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an overview of what you might need to do:

1. Parse the HTML.
2. Locate all links.
3. For each link:

   1. Parse the href attribute value as a URL.
   2. If it is relative and doesn't begin with / or ~/, then prefix / and set the href attribute.
4. Convert the parsed HTML back to text.

You may be able to use HtmlAgilityPack and System.Uri to do the parsing.